# Do something when $.get is fully completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a problem. I want to do something when my GET is fully completed, because I need to place BG in the middle. This function is totally working on resize, but this won't work when I load image onClick. Any way to avoid this one?

Example:

getBG.php returns `<img id="bgImage" src="123.jpg" />`

Problem:

It will not correctly calculate variable `a` because I think that it is trying to do that before image is even loaded. It works just fine onResize event when image is fully loaded.

```
$.get("getBg.php", {
            img: (this).id
        },
        function(data){
            $("#bg").html(data);
            var a = $("#bgImage").height() - $(window).height();
            $("#bgImage").css("margin-top", - a / 2);
        });
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking...   the call-back function runs when the ajax call is complete.  What is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hook the load event of the new image directly.
I'm assuming the element of #bgImage is the image, this is probably what you want.

```
$.get("getBg.php", {
            img: (this).id
        },
        function(data){
            $("#bg").html(data);
            $("#bgImage").load( function() {
                var a = $(this).height() - $(window).height();
                $(this).css("margin-top", - a / 2);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Strangely this does not solve the problem. If I add alert("test"); it is showing it up, but image is still not placed in the middle... Oh wait. It works on FF and IE but not on Chrome... :|

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `setTimeout` to loop until `$("#bgImage").height()` is greater than zero.